# Expressjs - How to GET '/' route for every request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Building an app with ExpressJs, users can now request a user profile with localhost:5000/user/12345.

Then, the server process it like this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

Problem is that Express takes the (wrong) '/user' route for all the files to send:

```
GET /user/client/css/fonts/font-awesome.min.css 304 1076.704 ms - -
```

How can I keep the '/' route ? Like this:

```
GET /client/css/fonts/font-awesome.min.css 304 1076.704 ms - -
```

Answer (score 1):

use this before defining your routes

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Already wrote that. I got this error client-side: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:5000/user/client/css/styles.css".

Comment: Resolved it by adding <base href="/"> to the head of the html.

Answer (score 1):

In order to request a specific user profile you must send the id of the user along the specific route. If you use * all your requests for resources will be responded by nodejs with that specific end-point that you have written.

Instead of what you use now, use :

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {

    // access the id with req.params.id;
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: I still have the wrong route for serving other files (css,...): GET /user/client/css/fonts/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: In your html what is the src of that resource ?

Comment: All my resources are in /client. Not /user/client. So I just want to remove all the nested routes (except the parameters): in this case I need to remove '/user'. Btw this is a single page application, using this kind of route to be more modular

Comment: You should place this before your routes defined

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));